# Is the series $\sum (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \tan^{-1}(n) )$ convergent$?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is the series $\sum (\frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \tan^{-1}(n) )$ convergent$?$

I couldn't find any suitable test for this series. I tried tests like comparison,root test, ratio test, raabe's, gauss, nothing is working.

Any suggestion$?$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

Use the fact that $$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)+\arctan(n)=\frac{\pi}{2},$$

for all $n>0$ and that $$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)\sim\frac{1}{n}\quad \text{when }n\to\infty ,$$ to prove that it diverges.

Comment: @orlp: it's quite famous and very easy to prove.

Comment: Oh I confused $\tan^{-1}$ with $\tanh$.

Comment: $Surb, I didn't expect, the solution could be that easy. I was trying to apply test directly on the given series and I forgot about simple equations.

Comment: @Mathsaddict: Don't worry, that happen sometimes :-)